# how to randomly generate spikes in pygame which are constantly moving down

Tags: python, pygame

im building a game in pygame in which a hot air balloon is constantly going up and spikes are coming down and hot air balloon has to dodge them. However i dont know how to randomly generate nicely spaced spikes which constantly moving downwards im having issue with randomly generating downward moving spikes.

here is the code:

```
import pygame
import random
import math

pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screenwid = 400
screenhigh = 500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenwid, screenhigh))

grey = (240,240,240)
black = (0,0,0)

initvel = 3
player_x = 100
player_y = 250
spikex= -100
spikey = -100

xchange = 0
ychange = 0
baloon = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/aliab/Downloads/hotair balloom.png')
baloon = pygame.transform.scale(baloon,(300, 300))
spike = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/aliab/Downloads/spikes.png')
spike = pygame.transform.scale(spike,(300, 300))
bg = pygame.image.load('E:/bgparacute.jpg')

def balloon(x,y):
    screen.blit(baloon,(x,y ))
def spikee(x,y):
    screen.blit(spike,(x,y ))
y = 0

run = True
while run:

    rel_y = y % bg.get_rect().height
    
    screen.blit(bg,(0,rel_y - bg.get_rect().height))
    if rel_y < screenhigh:
        screen.blit(bg, (0, rel_y))
    y +=1
        
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
    
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                xchange = -initvel
                ychange = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                xchange = initvel
                ychange = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                ychange = -initvel
                xchange = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                ychange = initvel
                xchange = 0

    if spikey == 100:
        print('hihiohug')
        spikex = random.randint(0, 400)
        spikey = random.randint(-20, 10)
    spikey += 2
    player_x += xchange
    player_y += ychange
    balloon(player_x,player_y)
    spikee(spikex, spikey)
         
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your program.  If you are looking to only have a few spikes on your screen, theoretically, you could just individually define the spikes and then randomly generate their starting position as in your code with some simple tweaks.

```
import pygame
import random
import math

pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screenwid = 400
screenhigh = 500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenwid, screenhigh))

grey = (240,240,240)
black = (0,0,0)

initvel = 2
player_x = 100
player_y = 250
spikex1 = -100
spikey1 = -100
spikex2 = -40
spikey2 = -100

xchange = 0
ychange = 0
baloon = pygame.image.load('Balloon.png')
baloon = pygame.transform.scale(baloon,(240, 240))
spike1 = pygame.image.load('Mine.png')                  # Multiple spike definitions (very simplistic)
spike1 = pygame.transform.scale(spike1,(30, 30))
spike2 = pygame.image.load('Mine.png')
spike2 = pygame.transform.scale(spike2,(30, 30))
bg = pygame.image.load('background-day.png')

def balloon(x,y):
    screen.blit(baloon,(x,y ))
def spikee(x,y):
    screen.blit(spike1,(x,y ))
    screen.blit(spike2,(x,y ))
    
y = 0

run = True
while run:

    rel_y = y % bg.get_rect().height
    
    screen.blit(bg,(0,rel_y - bg.get_rect().height))
    if rel_y < screenhigh:
        screen.blit(bg, (0, rel_y))
    y +=1
        
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
    
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                xchange = -initvel
                ychange = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                xchange = initvel
                ychange = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                ychange = -initvel
                xchange = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                ychange = initvel
                xchange = 0
                
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:      # Allow for a little more control of the balloon
            xchange = 0
            ychange = 0

    if spikey1 == 280:
        print('hihiohug')
        spikex1 = random.randint(0, 300)
        spikey1 = random.randint(-100, 10)  # Adjust the random start above the screen for the spike
        
    if spikey2 == 280:
        print('hihiohug')
        spikex2 = random.randint(0, 300)
        spikey2 = random.randint(-100, 10)  # Adjust the random start above the screen for the spike
        
    spikey1 += 1
    spikey2 += 1
    player_x += xchange
    player_y += ychange
        
    balloon(player_x,player_y)
    spikee(spikex1, spikey1)
    spikee(spikex2, spikey2)
         
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

This produced randomly generated spikes (mines in my test).

[image: Balloon Game]

However, you might want to define an array of spikes that are randomly placed just off of the display.  As an example of that, I am including a link to GitHub for you to pull down a simple game I call "Submarine".

[Submarine Game](https://github.com/cschuls/Submarine_Game)

It is an arcade like game where the submarine tries to avoid hitting underwater mines.  It effectively is running in a horizontal fashion as opposed to your vertical action, but the underlying premises are alike.  It has an array set up for storing underwater mine images that then appear on the screen.

[image: Submarine Game]

Give that a try and see if that moves you forward in your game.